# Is it possible to have empty RequestParam values use the defaultValue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

if I have a a request mapping similar to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "i", defaultValue = "10") int i) {
}
```

And then call this request with:

```
http://example.com/test?i=
```

I get the error message

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""'

I can solve this by either stopping the javascript client from sending empty parameters, or by accepting string values and only parsing if they are not found to be blank.

**UPDATE**: Later versions of spring now implement the originally desired behaviour.

I've just tested this in spring 4.3.5 and have found that the behaviour will now in fact turn the null value into the default value without raising a `NumberFormatException`, thus; my original mapping now works fine.

I am not sure which version of spring this behavioural change was made.

Comment: surely the parameter would be an Integer type to raise that exception?

Comment: im not spring expert, but is default value is used when you don't set it? ie if your request will be http://example.com/test ? as you use http://example.com/test?i= then i is present and set to "" so default value is not used

Comment: Thanks amir75, accidentally supplied `String` type. user902383, that's correct, though for an integer value I would prefer that a null/empty value would use the defaultValue instead.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You could change the @RequestParam type to an Integer and make it not required. This would allow your request to succeed, but it would then be null. You could explicitly set it to your default value in the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "i", required=false) Integer i) {
    if(i == null) {
        i = 10;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I have removed the defaultValue from the example above, but you may want to include it if you expect to receive requests where it isn't set at all:

```
http://example.com/test
```

Comment: Just an update on this, recent versions of spring actually no longer require the null check as the desired behaviour has been included with spring that empty values will result in the default value being used.

Comment: Obsolete answers, the best solution is from @AppLend

Comment: In modern Spring versions, it's called `defaultValue`, and `value` is just an alias to `name`.

Comment: I tried this, but still get the same error: `@RequestParam(required = false) Boolean password` and then `if (password != null && password)`. My Spring Boot version is 2.6.2

Comment: Does it return an empty String or something if there's no parameter? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 130):

You can keep primitive type by setting default value, in the your case just add **"required = false"** property:

```
@RequestParam(value = "i", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int i
```

P.S.
This page from Spring documentation might be useful:
[Annotation Type RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Comment: Thanks but you missed the point of my question which is in the title. I've asked for the ability to supply empty params `/test?i=` and since `i` is empty have the default value.

Comment: Anyway, when ```defaultValue``` was provided, ```required == false``` implicitly

Comment: If the param is provided but is empty `defaultValue` does not take effect.

Comment: Still does not work at least for `@GetMapping` request. The `defaultValue` is not set (`null` for `Integer`, empty string for `String`, fails with exception for `int`. :(

Answer (score 19):

You can set RequestParam, using generic class Integer instead of int,  it will resolve your issue.

```
   @RequestParam(value= "i", defaultValue = "20") Integer i
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@Nullable` with default value.

```
@Nullable @RequestParam(value = "i", defaultValue = "10") Integer i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this -

```
 @RequestParam(value= "i", defaultValue = "20") Optional<Integer> i
```

Comment: If you have a defaultValue, there's no need to make this an Optional.

Answer (score 2):

This was considered a bug in 2013: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10180

and was fixed with version 3.2.2. Problem shouldn't occur in any versions after that and your code should work just fine.