# Spring MVC @RequestParam DefaultValue Not set for parameter with emptyvalue

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am calling the URL and sending parameter as below -

```
 http://india.webinc.in:8080/caseManagement/caseView?lock=false&caseId=
```

It is landed into Spring MVC's below controller method -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/caseView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String caseView(
final HttpServletRequest request,   
@RequestParam(value = "caseId", defaultValue = "-1") final Integer caseId
){
System.out.println("request.getparameter(caseId)::" + request.getParameter("caseId"));
System.out.println("@RequestParam caseId::" + caseId);
if (caseId != -1) {
//do something
} else {
//do something else
} 
}
```

And generates the result as below in console -

```
request.getparameter(caseId)::
@RequestParam caseId::null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now as per doc default value can be used as a fallback when request parameter value is empty , then what could be the reason empty caseId not set to -1 ?

> http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html
>   
> "The default value to use as a fallback when the request parameter value is not provided or empty."

For a solution I have already excluded this caseId parameter from url, however I am curious to know the defalut behaviour of RequestParam.

Answer (score 0):

> Now as per doc default value can be used as a fallback when request parameter value is empty , then what could be the reason empty caseId not set to -1 ?

It seems that as long as the `caseId` param is present among the query parameters of your request, it is considered *provided* a value of "", thus the result you encounter. The

> provided or empty

part of the Spring documentation might be confusing but here is another example of the same behavior : [Is it possible to have empty RequestParam values use the defaultValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue)

Comment: m4rtin..Thanks ! I went through that post earlier..and I think requestor still remain unconvincing..and same with me. I think caseId value is empty so defaultValue should be available in controller.