# ModelAttribute doesn't reflect the default value of a requestParam if null

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have the below spring rest API :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponsePack getPacks(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "effDate", required = false) String effDate, @RequestParam(value = "cardType", defaultValue = "*") String cardType, @Valid @ModelAttribute Wrapper requestParamWrapper) {
```

`effDate` and `cardType` are the two params passed to this API (both are optional).

What I'm trying to do is set a default value of `*` to `cardType` if nothing is passed.

I can see that the String `cardType` has got the correct default value. How do i do something similar for the `requestParamWrapper's cardType` (in the model attribute) , i.e setting the default value `*` for `cardType` when the param is not passed.

Comment: Why should it. The request param doesn't influence the binding.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue

Comment: How do I do that binding ?

Comment: What is Wrapper? Is that your own class? You can set defaults using the set-method for that field.

Comment: @JackFlamp , Yeah my custom class, and yes I'm currently using setter. Just looking for any alternate annotations or something?