# How to give default value as integer in @RequestParam()

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to **spring boot** and learning `@RequestParam()`

I know that we can give defaultValue in String but when I am trying to give default value as Integer it's showing me an error.

```
@RequestMapping("/returnVeriable")
public int getVeriable(@RequestParam(required=true,defaultValue=1/*error here*/) int veri){
    return veri;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `defaultValue` is a `String` specify the default as a `String` value. That is also what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: @Siddhesh how about accepting one of the answers? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try with "" around integer to make it string as the defaultValue is implemented as String.

```
@RequestMapping("/returnVeriable")
public int getVeriable(@RequestParam(required=true,defaultValue="1") Integer veri){
    return veri;
}
```

refer : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5915

Comment: Although `required=true` together with `defaultValue` does not make much sense as `defaultValue` implicitly sets required to false.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: `Integer` can be null, but `int` cannot. If for some reason the param is blank, it would seem that they had put 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 11):

When a value traffic by HTTP protocol, it has no type. It's a String. And so it is at this parameter type at the annotation. Then, you do something like this:

`@RequestParam(required = true, defaultValue = "1") Integer veri`

And it will work fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTTP. Were it implemented differently, the Java @RequestParam could take an integer default value.

Comment: It could, but it’s not. And it will be a string that was never parsed to int before.

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
@RequestMapping("/returnVariable")
public int getVariable(@RequestParam(required=true,defaultValue="1") int var) {
    return var;
}
```

By default what ever you pass to the controller is treated as String and converted to respective types. So even default values need to be set as String

Comment: you are converting it into a String.. I want to use it as int.

Comment: @Siddhesh defaultValue allways has to be a String and will automatically be converted to the actual type. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12296642/6073886

Comment: HTTP Request Parameters are always `String`... The conversion from `String` to the actual type is done by Spring using `Converter`s and `PropertyEditor`s.

Comment: It is not coverted. See the return type of defaultValue() method in RequestParam class. it is a String. So you need to specify your int as String(with quotes). but the type of variable veri is still int as you can see in the above code

Comment: The origin of the annotation parameter type being `String` instead of `Object` isn't even with Spring. It comes from a limitation in Java itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458556/593146