# Sending id or age as requestparam in spring boot producing different results

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have recently started learning spring boot and when I am trying to pass id or age in postman to test it I am getting value as 1 for id and 25 for age (I have declared id and age as Integers in method parameter).

Here is a code from controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student/")

public class StudentController {

@GetMapping()
public Integer getStudents(  @RequestParam()  Integer id,@RequestParam()  Integer age ){

    
    return age;
    
}
```

Here is the screenshot from postman

[image]

When I declare id and age as Strings in method params The results are `1,value` for id and `25,value` for age .

For all the other queryparams the reults are as expected .

What is the reason for this? How does spring convert types?

Any help is appreciated . Thank you .

Comment: Did you try explicit param name like @RequestParam(“id”) and @RequestParam(“age”)?

Comment: yes I have tried . It gives the same result .

Answer (score 0):

As per this community issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/10584

I see a comment stating
`Annotation properties can only be of type String, Enumeration, Class, Annotation, primitives, or arrays of these types.`

Can you please try with `int` ?

Check this article too, if this is relating to your issue
[How to give default value as integer in @RequestParam()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813925/how-to-give-default-value-as-integer-in-requestparam)

Comment: Seems like the issue is happening only with the parameters as id or age because with other parameter names  the result is as expected . I have tried to change the id type to String  , Integer,int but the result is same . it returns 1 for id when return type is Integer and   "1 , valuePassed "   when the return type is String .