# SpringBoot: ModelAttribute default property through yml file not working

Tags: spring-boot, properties, yaml, modelattribute

Age limit default value is not picked by `ModelAttribute`, However it was working fine with request parameter.

YML File

```
age:            
    default:
        limit:  60
```

Below is old Code with Request Parameter Request

```
public ResponseEntity<Account> getPersonAccount(@RequestParam String name,@Min(value=0) @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "${age.default.limit}") Integer limit
){
}
```

Below is new Code with ModelAttribute Request

```
public ResponseEntity<Account> getPersonAccount(@ModelAttribute("person" ) Person person) {}

@Configuration
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    @Value("${age.default.limit}" )
    private Integer limit;
    getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Have you look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue

Comment: This post is different related to parameter only. I just want to initialize model attribute object's property from yml file.

Comment: You can't use yml properties anywhere and everywhere. "@Value" njects it into private variables via getters and setters. You can't assign defaultValue parameter in the "@RequestParam" just by putting the ${property} in there.

Comment: defaultValue = "${age.default.limit}" in request parameter was working fine from yml file. I only want to provide default value to new model object from yml file. I am looking solution for that only. getter/ setter are already there.

Comment: That's not how it works at all. For you to substitute a yml config item, you need '@Value'. You can't assign without using '@Value' and you can't use @Value in '@RequestParam'

Comment: I am looking for a solution, not problem. Once I found the way to do it. I will post it.

Comment: Opened Jira Issue: https://jira.spring.io/projects/SPR/issues/SPR-17041?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class PersonController { 
@Value("${age.default.limit}" )
private Integer limit;

@ModelAttribute("person")
public Person populatePerson() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setLimit(limit);
    return user;
}

public ResponseEntity<Account> getPersonAccount(@ModelAttribute("person" ) Person person) {}
```

}