# ignore optional @Query parameters

Tags: java, web-services, restful-authentication

Is there a possibility to ignore some of the optional `@Query` parameters dynamic if the corresponding value is not declared?

```
@Path("/users")
public class Services {

@GET
@Path("/get")
public Response getUsers(
    @QueryParam("from") int from,
    @QueryParam("to") int to,
    @QueryParam("age") int age,
    @QueryParam("name") String name
    @QueryParam("username") String username)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JAX-RS parameters are not mandatory, if you don't send value to parameters the default value will be `null`, you can also use `@DefaultValue` annotation to provide default value.

Use can also use spring frame work `@RequestParam` and you can specify `required=false` so which is optional
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue)

Comment: I do not want to include at all, the corresponding @Query parameter in the next query I want to make. it is as if not exists the specific value of parameter and not it has a default parameter.. Is it possible that?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you want to do `GET` call without some `@query` parameters (even though in the controller method you have them) right? yes if this is the case it will work, and the parameters which you don't include in query will set to `null` by default

Comment: if i send values to all the Query parameters, after i make a query for all of them.. Now If some of them stay null because i didn't send a value, i want to exclude them from the next query, and not give them a default value. Like the null parameter not exists

Comment: ya it will work, give a try without parameters and do `sysout` inside method

Answer (score 0):

You could use @DefaultValue so if the param is not filled you get the default value

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/