# validate input in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this input:

```
Masa: <input type="number"  class="form-control form-text"   name="masa"/>
    <div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${wzrost}" >
        <p class="text text-center">
            To pole jest wymagane
        </p>
    </div>
    Wzrost: <input type="number" class="form-control form-text "   name="wzrost"/>
    <div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${wzrost}" >
        <p class="text text-center">
            To pole jest wymagane
        </p>
    </div>
```

And this controller;

```
String x = String.valueOf(masa);
        String y = String.valueOf(wzrost);


        if(x==null ){
        model.addAttribute("wzrost",true);
        return"views/success";
    }
        if(y==null ){
            model.addAttribute("wzrost",true);
            return"views/success";
        }
```

When I click form submit button I always get error nullpointerexception.

How do I validate input, so that when it is empty the message pops up

Comment: Can you please post all your controller code and your full stack trace?  It should look something like: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to implement server side validation. For this the best approach is to use validators and its bindingResult. Steps to implement server side validation is

1. Have for model

   ```
   public class PersonForm {
     private String name;

    public String getName() {
       return this.name;
   }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Use form model in html

   ```
   <form action="#" th:action="@{/personForm}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td><label th:text="#{label.name}+' :'"></label></td>
           <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
           <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Generic Error</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
   ```

   3. Have validator class

   @Component

   ```
   public class PersonFormValidator implements Validator {
   @Override
   public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
       return PersonForm.class.equals(clazz);
   }

   @Override
   public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "name", "field.name.empty");
       PersonForm p = (PersonForm) target;

       if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("XXX")) {
           errors.rejectValue("name", "Name cannot be XXX");
       }
   }}
   ```

   4. Bind validator to controller and let spring do the magic.

   @Controller

   ```
   public class WebController {
   @Autowired
   PersonFormValidator personFormValidator;


   @InitBinder("personForm")
   protected void initPersonFormBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.addValidators(personFormValidator);
   }

   @PostMapping("/personForm")
   public String checkPersonInfo(@Validated PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
   if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
       return "personForm";
   }
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("personResult",  apiClientService.getPersonResult(personForm));
   return "redirect:/spouseForm";
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: But i dont use any  th:object="${personForm}" is only th:action

Comment: I can see that you as using `th:if="${wzrost}"` which is used in case of you want to show error message from server, so you must implement server side validation, my answer is example how i did it.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/cal-bmi")
public String calculateBmiForm(Model model, Integer masa, Integer wzrost) {

String x = String.valueOf(masa);
    String y = String.valueOf(wzrost);


    if(x==null ){
    model.addAttribute("wzrost",true);
    return"views/success";
}
    if(y==null ){
        model.addAttribute("wzrost",true);
        return"views/success";
    }
}
```

ANd when i get a valu form masa and wzrost i check from null, i click submit alwas nullpointerexception

```
 <form th:action="@{/cal-bmi}" method="post">

    <ul class="gender-options">
        <input id="man" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required  />
        <label for="man">mężczyzna</label> &frasl;
        <input id="woman" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>
        <label for="woman">kobieta</label>
    </ul>


    Masa: <input type="number" class="form-control form-text" required placeholder="(kg)" name="masa"/>

    <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${wzrost}">-->
        <!--<p class="text text-center">-->
            <!--To pole jest wymagane-->
        <!--</p>-->
    <!--</div>-->
    Wzrost: <input type="number" class="form-control form-text " required placeholder="(cm)" name="wzrost"/>

    <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${wzrost}">-->
        <!--<p class="text text-center">-->
            <!--To pole jest wymagane-->
        <!--</p>-->
    <!--</div>-->
    <input type="submit" class="col-lg-10 btn btn-primary" value="Oblicz"/>
</form>
```

Now i used required but is not good solution