# Why do I have a login issue after updating rows in my database?

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a user in my database and I would like to edit their information. I am trying to add their gender and height. The problem is, that after updating my user, I am unable to log in again. This error has been quite persisting and it always happens after updating my user.

This is my **HTML** code:

```
<form th:action="@{/editprofile/save}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
```

And my **Controller** code:

```
@PostMapping("/editprofile/save")
public String save(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect, Principal principal) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "views/success";
    }
    System.out.println(user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());
    System.out.println(user.getRepassword());

    userService.save(user);

    redirect.addFlashAttribute("success", "Saved employee successfully!");
    return "redirect:/editprofile";
}
```

Comment: Could you add your whole html form and your model's code?

Comment: Show your `save` method of the `UserService`.

Comment: I added full code  below

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is all form :

```
<form th:action="@{/editprofile/save}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="name"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center col-form-label">Imię: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" th:field="*{name}" id="name">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"-->
                <!--th:errors="*{name}"></div>-->
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="surname"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center col-form-label">Nazwisko: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text " th:field="*{surname}" id="surname">
                <div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}"
                     th:errors="*{surname}"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center  col-form-label">Adres
                Email: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-text "  th:field="*{email}" id="email">
                <div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
                     th:errors="*{email}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div  class="form-group row">
            <label for="password"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center  hidden col-form-label">Hasło: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control form-text " value="elko"  th:value="${user.getPassword()}" th:name="password"  id="password">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}"-->
                     <!--th:errors="*{password}">-->
                <!--</div>-->

            </div>
        </div>
        <div  class="form-group row">
            <label for="repassword" class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center   col-form-label">Powtórz
                Hasło: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input   type="text" class="form-control  form-text "  th:value="${user.getRepassword()}" th:name="repassword"  id="repassword">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('repassword')}"-->
                     <!--th:errors="*{repassword}">-->
                <!--</div>-->
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="surname"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center  col-form-label">Płec: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text " th:field="*{gender}" id="gender">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}"-->
                <!--th:errors="*{surname}"></div>-->
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="surname"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center  col-form-label">Data urodzenia: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text " th:field="*{birthdate}" id="birthdate">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}"-->
                <!--th:errors="*{surname}"></div>-->
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="surname"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center  col-form-label">Waga: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text " th:field="*{weight}" id="weight">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}"-->
                <!--th:errors="*{surname}"></div>-->
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="surname"
                   class="col-sm-2 pr-0 pl-0 text-center  col-form-label">Wzrost: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 cl-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text " th:field="*{growth}" id="growth">
                <!--<div class="text col-sm-12 error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}"-->
                <!--th:errors="*{surname}"></div>-->
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="col-lg-10 btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
```

And thsi is my controller save :

```
 @GetMapping("/editprofile")
public String editeProfile( Model model, Principal principal) {

    String email = principal.getName();
    User user = userService.findOne(email);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "views/editprofile";
}


@GetMapping("/editprofile/{email}")
public String editProfile( @PathVariable String email, Model model,Principal principal) {

    model.addAttribute("user", userService.findOne(email));
    return "views/editprofile";
}



@PostMapping("/editprofile/save")
public String save(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "views/success";
    }
    System.out.println(user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());
    System.out.println(user.getRepassword());

    userService.save(user);

    redirect.addFlashAttribute("success", "Saved employee successfully!");
    return "redirect:/editprofile";
}
```

Userservice :

```
  public void save(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for following the approach i guided on 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371025/10232467

Authentication and Authorization process is not defined in your given source code. We should use Spring Security to do this job. Please import spring security dependencies and make Security config class as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
          //  .loginPage("/login") in case if custom login page is required
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
    // add ant matchers and require secure in case if certain url has to be on https
    ;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

// for in memory authentication
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .withUser("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .roles("USER");
}
}
```

You can get logged in User details anytime in controller by below code

```
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
```