# Custom Validator Annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-validator

I created a custom validation to `<form:select>` that populate country list.

**Customer.jsp**

```
    Country: 
    <form:select path="country" items="${countries}" />
    <form:errors path="country" cssClass="error"/>
```

**FomeController.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String prosCustomer(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("defaultcustomer") Customer customer,
            BindingResult result
    ) {
        CustomerValidator vali = new CustomerValidator();
        vali.validate(customer, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "form/customer";
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }
```

**CustomValidator.java**

```
public class CustomerValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        return Customer.class.equals(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Customer customer = (Customer) target;
       int countyid=Integer.parseInt(customer.getCountry().getCountry());
        if (countyid==0) {
             errors.rejectValue("country",  "This value is cannot be empty");
        }
    }
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
   private Country country;
```

**Validation is working perfectly fine.** But the problem is that the validation method has attached another message too. 
[image: validation view]

Please tell me how to correct this message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the implementation of Validator in controller as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371025/10232467

So you controller method can be like

```
@Autowired
CustomerValidator customerValidator;


@InitBinder("defaultcustomer")
protected void initDefaultCustomerBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
binder.addValidators(customerValidator);
}

@PostMapping("/customer")
public String prosCustomer(@Validated Customer defaultcustomer, BindingResult bindingResult) {
// if error 
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return "form/customer";
}
// if no error
return "redirect:/sucess";
}
```

Additionally the form model name in jsp should be defined as "defaultcustomer"

EDIT :

I missed the nested Country object in Customer class. In validator replace

```
errors.rejectValue("country",  "This value is cannot be empty");
```

with

```
errors.rejectValue("defaultcustomer.country",  "This value is cannot be empty");
```

Also found that Customer class should be modified as

```
@Valid
private Country country;
```

Comment: can you share complete jsp code, does it displays defaultcustomer.country even when form is not submitted ?