# How to put a default value in an object with Annotation? (@RequestParam)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to give an object a default value using @RequestParam?

When I name the form tag the same as the field in the object
I know that it automatically assigns a value to an object.
But if the object's field is an int, null value is entered, an error occurs.

★ [Plant_list2VO class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aUHz.png)

★ [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH464.png)

★ [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8kcD.png):

```
public String reg4(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    Plant_list2VO plant_list2VO, 
                    @RequestParam(name="inv_count", defaultValue="0") int inv_count,
                    @RequestParam(name="inv_count_disable", defaultValue="2") int inv_count_disable,
                    Model model) {
    
}
```

★ console:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'plant_list2VO' on field 'inv_count': rejected value [];
    codes [typeMismatch.plant_list2VO.inv_count,typeMismatch.inv_count,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch];
    arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [plant_list2VO.inv_count,inv_count]; arguments [];
    default message [inv_count]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'inv_count'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]
Field error in object 'plant_list2VO' on field 'inv_count_disable': rejected value [];
    codes [typeMismatch.plant_list2VO.inv_count_disable,typeMismatch.inv_count_disable,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch];
    arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [plant_list2VO.inv_count_disable,inv_count_disable]; arguments []; default message [inv_count_disable]];
    default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'inv_count_disable'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you define inv_count and inv_count_disable are int attributes. So, you should change values of `defaultValue` to a number to resolve `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the console log, the `inv_count` and `inv_count_disable` values passed to your controller are not null, but empty Strings.

I can assume you use an old version of Spring, because before 3.2.x version empty String values were accepted by `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver` as actual values (see method `resolveArgument` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.1.x/org.springframework.web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java)), and `defaultValue` wasn't used in that case, resulting in conversion exception, because empty String cannot be converted to an integer.
In 3.2.x and later versions of Spring empty String is considered as there were no value passed, and `defaultValue` is used in case it's present (see method `resolveArgument` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java)).

So, if you want to stick to an older version of Spring, you may want to change your form to send some default number if the field is empty, or create a DTO, where these fields are of type `String` with some logic in setters.

Also this may help: [Is it possible to have empty RequestParam values use the defaultValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue)