# Ask for an answer about AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```java
    @RequestMapping("hello/one")
    @ResponseBody
    public Response<HelloResponse> helloOne(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id){
        if (id ==null || id == ""){
            throw new RuntimeException("error");
        }
        HelloResponse helloResponse = new HelloResponse();
        helloResponse.setList(list);
        return Response.success(helloResponse);
    }
```

When I use this method to access the `GET http://localhost:9999/hello/one` interface, a 400 bad request will appear.

When I use this method to access the `GET http://localhost:9999/hello/one?id=` interface, it is normal access, and the id parameter is "".

Question：

Why is required in the RequestParam attribute true, and only the `id=` request can be accessed normally? Shouldn't there be interception here? Is it reasonable to think the empty string is right?

If `id=` this access interface expects to return 400 bad request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have empty RequestParam values use the defaultValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296642/is-it-possible-to-have-empty-requestparam-values-use-the-defaultvalue)

Comment: required means the parameter has to be in the request, it doesn't require to have a value only that the parameter is there. If it isn't there is an exception.

Comment: For me it's the correct behavior that when you pass "id=" you get an empty string. When you don't pass the id parameter, you get null if the parameter is optional and an error when it's not optional, cf. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param.